# Apache2 restart while using wsf/php

Tags: php, apache2, wsh

I have another problem with framework WSF/PHP. Most of the time (not always, but still), when i run my script it ends with lost connection. There's no error page or anything, just error connecting with host (via localahost).

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $server_location = "https://some.address";
    $clientCert_location = "clientCert.pem";
    $CACert_location = "CACert.cer";
    $passphrase = "some.password";
    $request = file_get_contents("./requests/example.xml");
    $action = "some.action";

    $rec_cert = ws_get_cert_from_file($CACert_location);
    $pvt_key = ws_get_key_from_file($clientCert_location);
    $sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("privateKey" => $pvt_key,
                                           "receiverCertificate" => $rec_cert));

    $client = new WSClient(array("useSOAP" => "1.1",
                                 "policy" => new WSPolicy(array()),
                                 "securityToken" => $sec_token,
                                 "to"=>$server_location,
                                 "action" => $action,
                                 "CACert" => $CACert_location));

    try {
        $response = $client->request($request);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e instanceof WSFault) {
            $response = "Soap Fault: ".$e->Code."\n";
        } else {
            $response = "Message = ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

And here's error log from apache:

```
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  Cannot find path D:\Aplikacje\wsf-php-2.1.0\wsf_c/services.
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  [rampart] rampart_mod initialized
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  [rahas]Rahas module initialized
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [error] ..\..\axiom\src\om\om_document.c(102) Unable to get root node
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  Starting addressing out handler
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [warning] ..\..\src\core\context\msg_ctx.c(1384) RampartClientConfiguration not set in message context
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  [rampart][rampart_signature] No parts specified or specified parts can't be found for Signature.
OPENSSL_Uplink(100EC020,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  [rampart] rampart_mod shutdown
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:41 2011] [info]  [rahas] Rahas module shutdown
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:43 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:43 2011] [notice] Server built: May 20 2011 17:39:35
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:43 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4636
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [info]  Cannot find path D:\Aplikacje\wsf-php-2.1.0\wsf_c/services.
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [info]  [rampart] rampart_mod initialized
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [info]  [rahas]Rahas module initialized
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [notice] Child 4636: Child process is running
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [notice] Child 4636: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [notice] Child 4636: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Aug 29 11:13:44 2011] [notice] Child 4636: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Help will be much appreciated;)

**EDIT:**
I figured that out. My PATH was missing the .../php/ext location, so wsf.dll couldn't be found. However, it's not the end of my problem. More are comming... ;)

**EDIT2:**
Nope... It wasn't it:(

Comment: the forward slash here looks like it may be the culprit
`Cannot find path D:\Aplikacje\wsf-php-2.1.0\wsf_c/services`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem here. As i said, the script works from time to time, without changing the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone would be interested in how did it end, i solved the problem by upgrading apache-httpd to 2.2.21 and using [wse-php](http://code.google.com/p/wse-php/) instead of [wsf-php](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php/).